# $before/after_widget/title not displaying anything

Tags: widgets, sidebar, variables, register-sidebar

I have built a custom widget with this code:

```
class rfw_dock extends WP_Widget {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('rfw_dock', __('TITLE'), array( 'description' => __( 'DESCRIPTION')));
    }
    function widget($args, $instance) {
        $title = $instance['title'];
        $rss_url = $instance['rss_url'];
        $rss = fetch_feed($rss_url);
        $rss_items = $rss->get_items( 0, 1 );
        echo $before_widget;
        if ( $title )
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
        foreach ($rss_items as $item) {
            echo '<article><a href="'. esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ) .'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><h2>'. $item->get_title() .'</h2></a></article>';
        echo $after_widget;
        }
    }
    function form($instance) {
        $title     = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? esc_attr( $instance['title'] ) : '';
        $rss_url     = isset( $instance['rss_url'] ) ? esc_attr( $instance['rss_url'] ) : '';
        $number    = isset( $instance['number'] ) ? absint( $instance['number'] ) : 6; ?>
        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title (optional):' ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" /></p>
        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'rss_url' ); ?>"><?php _e('Enter the RSS feed URL here:'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'rss_url' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'rss_url' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $rss_url ); ?>" /></p><?php 
    }
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
        $instance['rss_url'] = strip_tags($new_instance['rss_url']);
        $instance['number'] = (int) $new_instance['number'];
        $instance['show_feed_title'] = ($new_instance['show_feed_title']==true);
        $instance['feed_words'] = (int) $new_instance['feed_words'];
        $instance['content_display'] = strip_tags($new_instance['content_display']);
        return $instance;
    }
}
register_widget('rfw_dock');`
```

And registered this sidebar:

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __('S&oslash;stersider'),
    'before_widget' => '<div>',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h6>',
    'after_title' => '</h6>'
) );
```

Pretty straight-forward, right? Well, my problem is that the `$before_title`, `$after_title`, `$before_widget` and `$after_widget` doesn't return anything, even though they're specified in the code. Isn't those variables how you're supposed to define the information in the register_sidebar? At least, it is in default-widgets.php.

I'm sorry, but I'm not the best in PHP, although I consider myself to have a medium-levelled knowledge in it. I've tried a lot before posting this, but nothing works. Can someone please help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out - I was missing the line `extract($args);` inside `function widget($args, $instance)`. Now everything works as expected.